# Rails App Error: Premature end of script headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

My setup: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Apache, Phusion Passenger, latest Ruby and Rails.

When I visit my website, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. 
Error Logfiles: Premature end of script headers

Does somebody know how to solve that problem?

Comment: `Premature end of script headers` this is in your apache logs, and is pretty useless on it's own. Do your rails logs give you any better information?

Comment: in production.log there is nothing special in my opinion. The last line is: Connecting to database specified by database.yml. I don't use a db yet and there is no db installed on the server. But i specified a postgresdb in database.yml . Could this cause that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a database configured for `production` in your `config/database.yml` that doesn't exist on the server as you mentioned in the comments, that could be the source of your issue since it's failing to establish a database connection.

Remove that connection from your `config/database.yml` and restart your app.

Answer (score 8):

Just posting here in case other people have the same problem as I did.

I followed the [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages) and part of that tutorial was making sure the `secret_token` was generated dynamically (listing 3.2 in the link) as a `.secret` file in the application root.

The problem was that the application somehow didn't write a token to the file, so I took the value from my development `.secret`, modified it, and saved it on the server. That made my application work in production.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I encountered exactly the same problem using dreamhost VPS.

I was doing 2 mistakes. Firstly i didnt run "bundle exec rake db:migrate" in production mode, i.e "bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"

but this problem still kept showing up. Then i tried Jesper8 answer. I ran "rake secret" and copied the secret token to config/secrets.yml file infront of "production:
  secret_key_base: "

Restarted my app and it worked

Hope this might help someone facing similar problem

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you environment is development:

`RailsEnv development`

Add to Virtualhost config

Comment: It may be a useful debugging step but this reads like a production server, and using a development rails environment in production is Not Great