# Ruby on Rails sometimes Premature end of script headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have and application in Ruby on Rails that connect with postgresql. The application is hosted in a shared hosting and the postgresql in a different shared server.

The applications works fine, but sometimes (many times) throws blank page with this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@fedecatjudo.cat and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

In server apache_error:

> [Wed Jun 17 10:13:30 2015] [error] [client XXX.XX.XX.XXX] Premature
>   end of script headers:

I think that the problem is the conection with postgres. I have the feeling when the application make a big query throw more times the error.

For these reason I put in config/database.rb timeout, but the error still appearing:

```
  adapter: postgresql 
  encoding: unicode
  database: xxx
  pool: 5
  timeout: 35000
  username: xxxx
  password: xxx
  host: xxx.xxx.com
```

Comment: have you gone through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419354/rails-app-error-premature-end-of-script-headers link

Comment: Yes, I read it. But my application works, is only sometimes that shows me this error.

Comment: Did you look at the PostgreSQL logs? If you enable more detailed logging in the application can you see anything in the app's logs?

Comment: There are any error in development.log. I'm talking to hosting to see the postgresql.log.

Comment: space on hosting server ? I encountered similar issue yesterday, when the usage showed up 100%

Comment: The disk usage is 77%. :S